# How to disable certificate validation in JAX-WS Client?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jax-ws

How do you disable certificate validation in JAX-WS client using `javax.xml.ws.Service`?

I tried creating an all-trusting TrustManager in the SSLSocketFactory and tried to bind it with BindingProvider

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 

Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) wsport ).getRequestContext(); 
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sc.getSocketFactory());
```

but I still getting `Exception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

But it works when I just use

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Or is there a way to make `javax.xml.ws.Service` use the `HttpsURLConnection` that I created?

Comment: Context is important. Why do you want to deliberately introduce a major insecurity? If you don't want it secure, why use HTTPS/SSL at all?

Comment: You'd be better off adding the untrusted certificate to the Java keystore

Comment: Why can't people just assume that others know what they are doing when trying to bypass SSL verification?

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution here:
http://schrepfler.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/relaxing-ssl-validation-for-jaxws.html

I'm using that solution calling the two static methods on a static block at the main class, like this:

```
static {
    SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
    SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** As David J. Liszewski pointed out, this **breaks SSL/TLS for all connections from this JVM**. So, keep that in mind.

Comment: Bravo. Break SSL/TLS for all connections from this JVM. :(

Answer (score 14):

The truth can be found from Erik Wramner's blog here http://erikwramner.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates-and-skip-host-name-verification-with-jax-ws

I include the full solution where Apache CXF is used to make SOAP web service requests to a self-signed SharePoint https service:

**NaiveSSLHelper.java**

```
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Map;

public class NaiveSSLHelper {
  public static void makeWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(
    Object webServicePort) {
    if (webServicePort instanceof BindingProvider) {
      BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) webServicePort;
      Map requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
      requestContext.put(JAXWS_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, getTrustingSSLSocketFactory());
      requestContext.put(JAXWS_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER,
        new NaiveHostnameVerifier());
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Web service port "
          + webServicePort.getClass().getName()
          + " does not implement "
          + BindingProvider.class.getName());
    }
  }

  public static SSLSocketFactory getTrustingSSLSocketFactory() {
    return SSLSocketFactoryHolder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private static SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory() {
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {
      new NaiveTrustManager()
    };
    SSLContext sslContext;
    try {
      sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      sslContext.init(new KeyManager[0], trustManagers,
        new SecureRandom());
      return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void makeCxfWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(HTTPConduit http) {
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
      new NaiveTrustManager()
    };
    TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLS");
    tlsParams.setKeyManagers(new KeyManager[0]);
    tlsParams.setTrustManagers(trustManagers);
    tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    http.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
  }

  private interface SSLSocketFactoryHolder {
    SSLSocketFactory INSTANCE = createSSLSocketFactory();
  }

  private static class NaiveHostnameVerifier implements
    HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostName,
                          SSLSession session) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  private static class NaiveTrustManager implements
    X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
  }

  private static final java.lang.String JAXWS_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER =
    "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier";
  private static final java.lang.String JAXWS_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY =
    "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory";
}
```

**SoapTester.java**

```
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.sitedata.ArrayOfSList;
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.sitedata.GetListCollectionResponse;
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.sitedata.SList;
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.sitedata.SiteData;
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.sitedata.SiteDataSoap;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.auth.HttpAuthHeader;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.auth.SpnegoAuthSupplier;
import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSName;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This example will invoke a web service on SharePoint 2013+ with optional kerberos auth.
 */
public class SoapTester {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapTester.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String endpointAddress = args[0];
    String keytabFilePath = args.length > 2 ? args[1] : null;
    String principalName = args.length > 2 ? args[2] : null;
    String servicePrincipalName = args.length > 3 ? args[3] : null;

    if (!endpointAddress.endsWith("/")) {
      endpointAddress += "/";
    }

    endpointAddress += "_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx";

    final String endpointAddressFinal = endpointAddress;

    Service service = Service.create(SiteData.SERVICE);
    SiteDataSoap soap = service.getPort(SiteDataSoap.class);
    NaiveSSLHelper.makeWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(soap);
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) soap;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC,
      Boolean.TRUE);
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
      BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointAddress);

    List<Handler> chain = bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
    chain.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
      @Override
      public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        String endpointAddress = (String) context.get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY);
        SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
          msg.writeTo(out);
          String str = new String(out.toByteArray());
          LOG.info("Sharepoint xml [" + endpointAddress + "]" + (outbound ? " (Outbound)" : " (Inbound)") + ": " + str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          LOG.error("Cannot get soap xml from message ", e);
        }
        if (outbound.booleanValue()) {
          try {
            context.getMessage().setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void close(MessageContext context) {
      }

      @Override
      public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
      }
    });
    bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(chain);
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(bindingProvider);

    client.getEndpoint().put("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements", System.getProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements") != null ? System.getProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements") : "5000000");
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    NaiveSSLHelper.makeCxfWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(http);

    AuthorizationPolicy authorization = new AuthorizationPolicy();
    authorization.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_NEGOTIATE);
    http.setAuthorization(authorization);

    SpnegoAuthSupplier authSupplier = new SpnegoAuthSupplier();
    if (servicePrincipalName != null) {
      authSupplier.setServicePrincipalName(servicePrincipalName);
      authSupplier.setServiceNameType(GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
    }

    Map<String, String> loginConfig = new HashMap<>();
    loginConfig.put("useKeyTab", "true");
    loginConfig.put("storeKey", "true");
    loginConfig.put("refreshKrb5Config", "true");
    loginConfig.put("keyTab", keytabFilePath);
    loginConfig.put("principal", principalName);
    loginConfig.put("useTicketCache", "true");
    loginConfig.put("debug", String.valueOf(true));
    authSupplier.setLoginConfig(new Configuration() {
      @Override
      public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
        return new AppConfigurationEntry[] {
          new AppConfigurationEntry("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule",
            AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
            loginConfig)};
      }
    });
    http.setAuthSupplier(authSupplier);

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    httpClientPolicy.setAutoRedirect(true);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

    Holder<ArrayOfSList> vLists = new Holder<>();
    Holder<Long> getListCollectionResult = new Holder<>();
    soap.getListCollectionAsync(getListCollectionResult, vLists, res -> {
      try {
        GetListCollectionResponse listCollectionResponse = res.get();
        ArrayOfSList arrayOfSList = listCollectionResponse.getVLists();
        LOG.info("Successfully got {} lists from {}", arrayOfSList.getSList().size(), endpointAddressFinal);
        for (SList slist : arrayOfSList.getSList()) {
          LOG.info("Successfully got list {}", slist.getTitle());
        }
        System.exit(0);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("List collection response", e);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is another example with respect to JDK7 and glassfish. Please pay attention for Nikolay Smirnov's comment as well. I use jdk 7 and glassfish 3.1.2. In this environment the suggested solution works perfect if the server deal with a self signed cerfificate.

```
// import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

/**
 *
 * Usage examples (BindingProvider port):
 * NaiveSSLHelper.makeWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(port); // GlassFish
 * NaiveSSLHelper.makeCxfWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(port); // TomEE
 * 
 * Based on Erik Wramner's example frome here:
 * http://erikwramner.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates-and-skip-host-name-verification-with-jax-ws/
 *
 * I have extended the functionality when Apache CXF is used.
 */
public class NaiveSSLHelper {

    private static final String JAXWS_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER = "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier"; // JAXWSProperties.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
    private static final String JAXWS_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY = "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory"; // JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY;

    // In Glassfish (Metro) environment you can use this function (Erik Wramner's solution)
    public static void makeWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(Object webServicePort) {
        if (webServicePort instanceof BindingProvider) {
            BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) webServicePort;
            Map requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
            requestContext.put(JAXWS_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, getTrustingSSLSocketFactory());
            requestContext.put(JAXWS_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, new NaiveHostnameVerifier());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Web service port "
                    + webServicePort.getClass().getName()
                    + " does not implement "
                    + BindingProvider.class.getName());
        }
    }

    // In TomEE (Apache CXF) environment you can use this function (my solution)
    public static void makeCxfWebServiceClientTrustEveryone(Object port) {
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
            new NaiveTrustManager()
        };
        Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) c.getConduit();
        TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
        tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("SSL");
        tlsParams.setKeyManagers(new KeyManager[0]);
        tlsParams.setTrustManagers(trustManagers);
        tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
    }

    public static SSLSocketFactory getTrustingSSLSocketFactory() {
        return SSLSocketFactoryHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory() {
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
            new NaiveTrustManager()
        };
        SSLContext sslContext;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(new KeyManager[0], trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static interface SSLSocketFactoryHolder {

        public static final SSLSocketFactory INSTANCE = createSSLSocketFactory();
    }

    private static class NaiveHostnameVerifier implements
            HostnameVerifier {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostName,
                SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static class NaiveTrustManager implements
            X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better than Jose Renato's answer. The solution from the link is said not to work in all cases, but at least for me (with OpenJdk 1.8, and whatever JAX-WS implementation NetBeans 8.2 uses) it worked fine. Would you copy it here, to protect against potential future disappearance of the linked page?

Comment: I have added the solution itself based on @pvgoran suggestion. I have also included the case when ApacheCXF is used.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for editing and cleaning my sentences :) Now it is easier to read :)

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside all security issues that come with it, if anyone still want to disable certificate validation in a JAX-WS Client. This is how i do.

NB: And this way, instead of breaking SSL/TLS for ALL connections, **you disable certificate validation for THAT client only.**

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

/** Custom JAX-WS client factory used to ignore certificate validation */
public class NotSecureClientFactory extends JaxWsProxyFactoryBean {

    @Override
    protected ClientProxy clientClientProxy(Client c) {
        // Create a client factory that does not validate certificate chains
        ClientProxy cp = super.clientClientProxy(c);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) cp.getClient().getConduit();
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters());
        return cp;
    }

    public TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

        TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        tlsClientParameters.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts);
        return tlsClientParameters;
    }

}
```

Comment: The hostname verifier still errors out with this solution. Miklos also has an answer for a specific client.

Comment: Sorry, no hostname verification error on my side. Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: setting tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true); makes it work. This solution is a lot simpler. Thanks. Also adding  how to use this factory would be helpful. This is what I used:
`NotSecureClientFactory factory = new NotSecureClientFactory();
        factory.setServiceClass(YourPort.class);
        factory.setAddress(address);
        YourPort port = (YourPort) factory.create();`

Answer (score 2):

Actually CXF comes w/ an [InsecureTrustManager](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/https/InsecureTrustManager.html) for testing purpose.

For a Spring Boot app, it would be as easy as the following to disable TLS validation in all your CXF clients. Needless to say, u should **NEVER** do this in a prod env.

```java
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.https.InsecureTrustManager;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import java.util.Set;

@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "soap.validate-tls.client", havingValue = "true")
@Configuration
class DisableTlsCxfClientConfig {
    @Inject
    DisableTlsCxfClientConfig(Set<BindingProvider> soapClients) {
        var insecureTlsParam = new TLSClientParameters();
        insecureTlsParam.setTrustManagers(InsecureTrustManager.getNoOpX509TrustManagers());
        insecureTlsParam.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        soapClients.stream()
                .map(ClientProxy::getClient)
                .map(Client::getConduit)
                .map(HTTPConduit.class::cast)
                .forEach(c -> c.setTlsClientParameters(insecureTlsParam));
    }
}
```

Shout out to @addiene, @jontro & @Miklos Krivan who provided all the pieces! Thank u very much!